# Why this JQuery plugin won't work?

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, grid

I'm trying to make this grid image organizer plugin work on my blog, but I can't seem to find a way for it to do it.

http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/

Apparently all I need to do is to put the jquery src reference, the jquery plugin src reference and call the function for a certain div which the plugin is gonna be applied.

This is the code which I'm trying to apply it:

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

</style>

<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"> </script>
<script src = "http://f.cl.ly/items/0O3A2k2d3K360u34473D/grid-a-licious.js"> </scipt>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").gridalicious();
});

</script>


</head>

<body>

<div id = "container">
<img src= "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kzjlfiTnfe1qz4rgho1_500.jpg"/>  
<img src= "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwh5eeaHae1qgf9y4o1_500.gif"/>  
<img src= "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lw3xaouWBm1qjg75jo1_500.jpg"/>  
<img src= "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2i55maEmI1qdqv28o1_500.png"/>  
<img src= "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2g0fpyDgn1r7j6ouo1_500.gif"/>  
<img src= "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m56ffozeAb1r3qiz4o1_500.gif"/>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you look in your browser error console or the debugger console for script errors?  That's nearly always the #1 thing you should do when things don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
<script src = "http://f.cl.ly/items/0O3A2k2d3K360u34473D/grid-a-licious.js"> </scipt>
```

Fix:

```
</script>
```

...forgot the `r` :)

*edit*

It looks like the `<img/>` tags each need to be inside of a `<div/>`, with a class of `item`. Try this as your `<body/>`:

```
<body>    
    <div id = "container">
        <div class="item">
            <img src= "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kzjlfiTnfe1qz4rgho1_500.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src= "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwh5eeaHae1qgf9y4o1_500.gif"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src= "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lw3xaouWBm1qjg75jo1_500.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src= "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2i55maEmI1qdqv28o1_500.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src= "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2g0fpyDgn1r7j6ouo1_500.gif"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src= "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m56ffozeAb1r3qiz4o1_500.gif"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```